# Como puedo utilizar una DLL escrita en C

Tags: c#, c, vb.net, visual-studio

Soy un poco nuevo con esto de manejo de librerias.

Resulta que necesito utilizar la libreria GNU Libmicrohttpd que se encuentra en este link https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/.

Esta librería el inconveniente que me he encontrado es que está escrita en C y el proyecto que estoy realizando es en .Net y al intentar adicionar la dll en Visual studio me marca el siguiente error:

[image: Error]

Que posibilidad puedo tener para adicionarla al proyecto? Agradezco de su colaboración

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero que tienes que saber es si esta librería esta compilada en modo "windows", de ser así podrás usar los `PINVOKES` para poder llamar a la librería.

En [este](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx) enlace podrás ver un tutorial completo de como hacerlo.

Aun así,un breve resumen es que tendrás que definir las funciones que necesites invocar desde tu código con DLLIMPORT definiendo una funcion intermediaria para invocar a la de la librería.

Sería algo así:

```
public class TestPInvoke
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int MessageBoxA(int h, string m, string c, int type);

    public static void Main() 
    {
        MessageBoxA(0, "Buenas!", "mensaje desde windows", 0);
    }
}
```